# Horizontal bar chart with outline behind bar

Tags: highcharts

We'd like to render the following chart using Highcharts. We've got most of it done except the dark grey background behind each bar. We need them to always cover the full width of the chart.

We'd rather not add a new series because the gray background does not represent any data in our application, it is purely an aesthetic choice. It feels like a hack to add a data series for a look & feel requirement. Furthermore, now we have to manage the axis maximum ourselves, instead of letting HighCharts just figure it out for us.

Is this possible to do in HighCharts or are we stuck with the new Series approach?

I don't have our code in a state where I can just pull it out, but let's start with this based on a HighCharts sample: http://jsfiddle.net/92SFh/. I'm sure I can adapt any technique we use here.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Population (millions)',
                align: 'high'
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' millions'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Year 2008',
            data: [973, 914, 4054, 732, 34]
        }]
    });
});
```

[image: chart]

Comment: Do you have most of it done in Highcharts? If so, can we get a JS Fiddle or at least see some code? By the dark grey background, do you mean the background behind the bars, or the background for the entirety of the chart area? Details, please. (And, yes, you can probably do this in Highcharts).

Comment: Added jsfiddle, preferably no "add a dummy data series" hacks. :)

Comment: What you are doing is showing a stacked bar chart, whether the idea is to pretend it's "behind" or not.
So...the solution really is to add a series to fill in the rest of the stacked portion.  It's not a hack, it's the answer...

Comment: Sure that's one way to look at it, and that's my mistake for not communicating properly. The dark gray background area is not driven by data at all. We have model objects populated by an API call that drives the chart's red/white series, not the gray background. Adding it in javascript on top of the actual data is a hack. If we choose this route, we get into things like having to define the axis maximum manually. I was hoping there was a more easy approach like point.background or something under plot options that I am missing. If this is the only approach, we'll use it.

Comment: Edited the question. Good feedback, I wasn't clear enough in our intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another solution, than using series. In the fact there are three other options, none of them is easy, so:

- use `plotBands` - will work only with fixed number of bars and fixed height of a chart: http://jsfiddle.net/92SFh/4/
- use renderer to draw background rects, see [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.rect) - but you need to manually find all values x/y/width/height to draw such rect.
- wrap drawing points to draw not only bar, but grey shape also, demo: http://jsfiddle.net/92SFh/6/

I think third option is the best for you, but requires more knowledge of Highcharts core than any of others.

And regarding min/max for yAxis - you don't have to calculate anything. Just create second yAxis, which won't be connected to first one, set `maxPadding: 0` and link that dummy series to second yAxis. All values in that series for second yAxis may be anything (but must be the same!).

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/92SFh/2/

This should get you very close. It uses the highcharts rounded corners plugin and ungroups the series so that they overlap. You can modify it to your liking.

To get the rounded corners using the plugin, add this to the series:

```
borderRadiusTopLeft: 8,
borderRadiusTopRight: 8
```

And to make them not overlap...

```
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                grouping: false
            }
        },
```

Comment: Good answer, not exactly what we were hoping the solution would be. I gave this an up vote but will only mark it as answer of adding a series is the best or only approach. Thanks.

Comment: You can also use [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.rect), but it seems to be more complicated.